# Mix-Blend mode doesn't work on custom cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a `mix-blend-mode: difference` to the inner cursor, but I can't get it to work. I heard that the `position: fixed` applied to the cursor may cause the problem here. But I can't remove that property, because the cursor needs to follow when scrolling down. Does anyone know how to fix the problem here? Thank you in advance.

```js
class Demo {
  constructor() {
    this.initCursor();
    this.initHovers();
  }
 

  initCursor() {
    const { Back } = window;
    this.outerCursor = document.querySelector(".circle-cursor-outer");
    this.innerCursor = document.querySelector(".circle-cursor-inner");
    this.outerCursorBox = this.outerCursor.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.outerCursorSpeed = 0;
    this.easing = Back.easeOut.config(1.7);
    this.clientX = -100;
    this.clientY = -100;
    this.showCursor = false;

    const unveilCursor = () => {
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, {
        x: this.clientX,
        y: this.clientY
      });
      TweenMax.set(this.outerCursor, {
        x: this.clientX - this.outerCursorBox.width / 2,
        y: this.clientY - this.outerCursorBox.height / 2
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.2;
      }, 100);
      this.showCursor = true;
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", unveilCursor);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      this.clientX = e.clientX;
      this.clientY = e.clientY;
    });

    const render = () => {
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, {
        rotation: 90,
        x: this.clientX,
        y: this.clientY
      });
      if (!this.isStuck) {
        TweenMax.to(this.outerCursor, this.outerCursorSpeed, {
          x: this.clientX - this.outerCursorBox.width / 2,
          y: this.clientY - this.outerCursorBox.height / 2
        });
      }
      if (this.showCursor) {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", unveilCursor);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  initHovers() {
    const handleMouseEnter = e => {
      this.isStuck = true;
      const target = e.currentTarget;
      const box = target.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.outerCursorOriginals = {
        width: this.outerCursorBox.width,
        height: this.outerCursorBox.height
      };
      TweenMax.to(this.innerCursor, 0.2, {
        x: box.left,
        y: box.top,
        width: box.width,
        height: box.height,
        opacity: 0.4,
      });
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
      this.isStuck = false;
      TweenMax.to(this.innerCursor, 0.2, {
        width: this.outerCursorOriginals.width,
        height: this.outerCursorOriginals.height,
        opacity: 0.2,
      });
    };

    const mainNavHoverTween = TweenMax.to(this.innerCursor, 0.3, {
      ease: this.easing,
      paused: true,
      opacity: 1,
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      left: -35,
      top: -35
    });

    const mainNavMouseEnter = () => {
      this.outerCursorSpeed = 0;
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, { opacity: 1 });
      mainNavHoverTween.play();
    };

    const mainNavMouseLeave = () => {
      this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.2;
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, { opacity: 1 });
      mainNavHoverTween.reverse();
    };

    const mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    mainNavLinks.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("mouseenter", mainNavMouseEnter);
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", mainNavMouseLeave);
    });

  







  }
}

const demo = new Demo();
```

```css
body{
  height: 500vh;
}

a{
  color: black;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.circle-cursor-outer-badge {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
.circle-cursor-inner {
  width: 22.5px;
  height: 22.5px;
  left: -11.25px;
  top: -11.25px;
  z-index: 11000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a href="#">I am a link</a>
  <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor-outer">
    <img class="circle-cursor-outer-badge" draggable="false" width="120" src="https://svgshare.com/i/H2V.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor-inner"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: All right, I just didn't want the question to be too similar to other questions related to that topic. Also, the cursor doesn't work without the JavaScript.

Comment: Gotcha. It might be fine then since the change is probably minimal and localized, so the extra code shouldn't be too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `background:white` to both `body` and `.circle-cursor-inner`:

```js
class Demo {
  constructor() {
    this.initCursor();
    this.initHovers();
  }
 

  initCursor() {
    const { Back } = window;
    this.outerCursor = document.querySelector(".circle-cursor-outer");
    this.innerCursor = document.querySelector(".circle-cursor-inner");
    this.outerCursorBox = this.outerCursor.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.outerCursorSpeed = 0;
    this.easing = Back.easeOut.config(1.7);
    this.clientX = -100;
    this.clientY = -100;
    this.showCursor = false;

    const unveilCursor = () => {
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, {
        x: this.clientX,
        y: this.clientY
      });
      TweenMax.set(this.outerCursor, {
        x: this.clientX - this.outerCursorBox.width / 2,
        y: this.clientY - this.outerCursorBox.height / 2
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.2;
      }, 100);
      this.showCursor = true;
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", unveilCursor);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      this.clientX = e.clientX;
      this.clientY = e.clientY;
    });

    const render = () => {
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, {
        rotation: 90,
        x: this.clientX,
        y: this.clientY
      });
      if (!this.isStuck) {
        TweenMax.to(this.outerCursor, this.outerCursorSpeed, {
          x: this.clientX - this.outerCursorBox.width / 2,
          y: this.clientY - this.outerCursorBox.height / 2
        });
      }
      if (this.showCursor) {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", unveilCursor);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  initHovers() {
    const handleMouseEnter = e => {
      this.isStuck = true;
      const target = e.currentTarget;
      const box = target.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.outerCursorOriginals = {
        width: this.outerCursorBox.width,
        height: this.outerCursorBox.height
      };
      TweenMax.to(this.innerCursor, 0.2, {
        x: box.left,
        y: box.top,
        width: box.width,
        height: box.height,
        opacity: 0.4,
      });
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
      this.isStuck = false;
      TweenMax.to(this.innerCursor, 0.2, {
        width: this.outerCursorOriginals.width,
        height: this.outerCursorOriginals.height,
        opacity: 0.2,
      });
    };

    const mainNavHoverTween = TweenMax.to(this.innerCursor, 0.3, {
      ease: this.easing,
      paused: true,
      opacity: 1,
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      left: -35,
      top: -35
    });

    const mainNavMouseEnter = () => {
      this.outerCursorSpeed = 0;
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, { opacity: 1 });
      mainNavHoverTween.play();
    };

    const mainNavMouseLeave = () => {
      this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.2;
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, { opacity: 1 });
      mainNavHoverTween.reverse();
    };

    const mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    mainNavLinks.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("mouseenter", mainNavMouseEnter);
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", mainNavMouseLeave);
    });

  







  }
}

const demo = new Demo();
```

```css
body{
  height: 500vh; 
  background:white;
}

a{
  color: black;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.circle-cursor-outer-badge {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
.circle-cursor-inner {
  width: 22.5px;
  height: 22.5px;
  left: -11.25px;
  top: -11.25px;
  z-index: 11000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a href="#">I am a link</a>
  <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor-outer">
    <img class="circle-cursor-outer-badge" draggable="false" width="120" src="https://svgshare.com/i/H2V.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor-inner"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this doesn't seem to work in Chrome. For me the inner cursor stays white. In Safari, it works. Edit: Fixed the problem by using an intermediate div for the body.